Issue Importing CSV File Using Filament v3.1
I'm encountering an issue while trying to import a CSV file using Filament version 3.1. I suspect the problem lies with the default file-upload.js script provided by Filament. Here are the details:

I'm using Filament v3.1 for my project.
When attempting to import a CSV file, an error occurs that seems to originate from file-upload.js.

Here are the steps I've already taken:

Ensured that I am using the latest version of Filament.
Double-checked my configuration and the script I am using.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I have created a video showing the error that occurs when trying to import the CSV file. You can watch the video at error importing csv file.
Has anyone else experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?
Thank you in advance for your help!


You should try looking console errors . Look again while importing CSV.
Verify CSV file permissions
3.Update Dependencies: Make sure all your dependencies are up-to-date, including Laravel, Livewire, and Filament.
Check Filament Configuration

